# Why PurgeCSS in Next.js removes all website styles? Need assistance with the configuration

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, purgecss

I'm using NextJs v.14 with Tailwind CSS and have encountered an issue where PageSpeed Insights warns me to reduce the amount of unused CSS. After some investigation, I found recommendations to install the PurgeCSS plugin to address this issue.

I installed and configured it according to the recommendations from the NextJs official website, but now it purges all styles from my website.

I've spent many hours trying to fix the issue and have explored all similar topics on StackOverflow, but I haven't been able to find an appropriate solution, and I'm really frustrated now. I would appreciate any help!

```
// my postss.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // restore the Next.js default behavior
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
    [
      "postcss-preset-env",
      {
        autoprefixer: {
          flexbox: "no-2009",
        },
        stage: 3,
        features: {
          "custom-properties": false,
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      // configure PurgeCSS
      "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
      {
        content: [
          "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
          "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
          "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
          "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mjs}",
        ],
        defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
        safelist: {
          standard: ["html", "body"],
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

And also for now I kept tailwid config file

```
// my tailwind.config.ts   
import { nextui } from "@nextui-org/react";

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mjs}",
  ],
  safelist: {
    standard: ["html", "body"],
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
    },
  },
  darkMode: [],
  plugins: [nextui()],
};
```

And just in case my package json

```
// my package.json
{
  "name": "charmy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nextui-org/react": "^2.2.9",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.16",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "next-sitemap": "^4.2.3",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^9.5.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably something conflicting between postcss and Tailwind. Have you looked at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production ?

Comment: yes I checked this page too
Actually settings for content completely the same in both files. So theoretically even if they rewrite each other they should rewrite the same settings

Comment: seems like it doesn't see the pathes in content array. I even tried to add explicitly pathes to the files where I use css classes. And it still purge ALL css

Comment: You don't need Purgecss, since Tailwind 3 which only writes the styles that are in use.

Comment: @SethWarburton Unfortunately I wasn't able to configure it in this way unfortunately. It always adds all styles into the css bundle (I'm using ssr in my project). I wish I would be abe to use only Tailwind as PurgeCss is really unpredictable and purges too much stuff

Comment: The production bundle would only contain those that match the globs in your config content key, suspect that is maybe too broad. For instance, you are including all the styles for the entire @nextui-org theme, which does not seem correct. Your content key should only point to the components in _your_ app. Did you try following the official Tailwind / Next integration docs? Your project setup looks quite different…

Comment: The issue is that actually I followed Next official guide but it still works not as expected. And when I don't include @nextui-org in content then all styles for it purged because I use Next UI component and there's no classes for them in my components which I add to content array

Comment: I just checked one more mote time NextUI docs, they are implicitly saying to add to content theme folder   content: [
    // ...
    "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
https://nextui.org/docs/guide/installation
@SethWarburton